# Wordpress plugin options need to delete after deactivate & uninstall

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

I have developed a wordpress plugin and I need to delete the options I am creating when uninstalling. What I did is I created a file called uninstall.php and included the following code:

```
<?php

function WCM_Setup_Demo_on_uninstall()
{
//if uninstall not called from WordPress exit
if ( !defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) 
    exit();

$video-thumbnail1 = 'video-thumbnail1';


// For Single site
if ( !is_multisite() ) 
{
    delete_option( $video-thumbnail1 );
} 
}
?>
```

And included this in my main plugin file:

```
register_uninstall_hook('uninstall.php', 'WCM_Setup_Demo_on_uninstall');
```

This is how i'm registering the option in my main plugin file:

```
register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'video-thumbnail1' );
```

When I deactivated and deleted the plugin from the dashboard, the plugin gets deactivated but not deleted. When one press delete a blank white page comes up.

Comment: When developing, always [turn on debug mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)!

Answer (score 0):

Blank/white page comes up probably due to wrong variable name. It should be `$video_thumbnail1` instead of `$video-thumbnail1`. No need to use a variable when you can directly use the option `video-thumbnail1`.

Also deactivate and delete are two different functionalities. Please refer to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook) for uninstallation hook.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `$video-thumbnail1` is defined incorrectly. You cant have `-` in the variable. Change it to `$video_thumbnail1`.